# How to use DOM to read XML within Android applications correctly?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, dom, xmlpullparser

I'm able to get the information I want if the XML file is stored locally on my machine, but reading it when stored on the phone isn't working very well.

I've tried XMLPullParser but it extracts binary information about the id names etc and I'd like the actual name.

Code:

```
    final String ANDROID_ID = "android:id";

            try {
                File fXmlFile = new File("res/layout/page1.xml");
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                        .newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Button");

                for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                        if (eElement.hasAttribute(ANDROID_ID))
                            System.out.println("ID: "
                                    + eElement.getAttribute(ANDROID_ID));
                    }
                }
            } 

            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Catch");


  e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

in the [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#getAttributeCount%28%29) documentation there is a getAttributeCount() and getAttributeByName(int index) that might be useful. You must use it in `START_TAG`

Comment: I tried to use the methods you proposed. The id value however comes out as a number when I was hoping it would come out as something similar to '@+id/page1'. I edited my first post with my new code and output.

Comment: It's probably because it's a "binary" XML file, meaning it's been precompiled for efficiency. I think you want to read the plain XML instead.

Comment: It will be more complicated since you will have to instantiate your own XmlPullParser, but you can probably get the raw xml InputStream using `res.openRawResource(R.layout.the_id)`.

Comment: @dmon I wrote another method earlier which used DOM to read the XML file but it wasn't able to get the XML resource (although it could if it was stored locally on my machine). I think it could be to do with not referencing the resource properly or the code? I have edited the code above with this other DOM method.

Comment: I've never done this so it was just a hunch. Instead of referencing the file like that, try using the `res.openRawResource()` method that I suggested and pass that InputStream it into the `DocumentBuilder`.

Comment: @dmon The openRawResource method works if I put the xml file into the res/raw folder. This way it doesn't get the ids out in binary.

Comment: Yup, that would do it too. The only bad thing is that you have to duplicate files :( .

Answer (score 0):

Over XML parsing this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) describes well. Here you can find other parsers too with `xmlPullParser`.