# how read xml file from res folder

Tags: android

I want to load data from an XML file and assign that data to variables in my Android app.

After doing some research on the various XML parsers available to Android, I figure the best parser method to use would be SAX.

I've read through a bunch of posts about reading XML from Android however I can't find one that uses a local file in the 'res' folder.

All the tutorials I've found are loading the XML file via a URL.

Is there a way to load the XML from the res folder?

Thanks

Comment: I just read this in one of the many tutorials: As an aside, if you'd like to parse non-compiled resources, such as those from the net, you should probably use SAX (for speed) or DOM (for versatility) instead. The Android pull parser is specifically geared to working well on compiled XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at my past question regarding the same issue: [How to use DOM to read XML within Android applications correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202864/how-to-use-dom-to-read-xml-within-android-applications-correctly)

From my experience I've copied the xml file into the `res/raw` folder and was able to read it correctly there using `res.openRawResource(R.raw.the_id)`. You can load it from the `res/layout` folder but some of the information when you parse it may be in binary, which wouldn't be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Put the xml into /res/raw folder. It looks like openRawResource opens resources from that folder only. You can also try getResources().getXml(com.MYCLass.R.xml.programs); which will return you instance of XML parser.

Comment: would/could I still use the SAX parser or do I need to use another type of XML parser for this?  Thanks

Comment: I would recommend using http://jsoup.org/ very easy to implement i use it for many projects.

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
 InputStream is=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_xml);
```

to get an input stream to your XML, and then use [XMLPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) to parse the file :

```
 XmlPullParser xpp=XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
 xpp.setInput(is,"your-encoding");
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant use a xml file in raw folder. because this error occurred : "Expected resource of type raw."
but u can easily place this xml file in assets folder and use it with :

```
 is = getAssets().open("myFedd.xml") ;
```